# Get Return Integer Value from a super class

Tags: java, return-value

This is the code I have in my first class:

```
public class Factorial {
public void Sequence(){
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of which you want your shit.");
    System.out.println("Factorial:");
    System.out.println(fact(Integer.valueOf(value)));
    getValues(Integer.valueOf(value));
}

public static int getValues(int n){
    return n;
}
```

And this is a subclass of Factorial:

```
public class Fibonacci extends Factorial {
    public void Sequence(){
        Factorial get = new Factorial();
                //not working EDIT: Just realized this obv wont work, but still need help to get it to work
        get.getValues(n);
```

However I cannot get the Value returned in the getValues from the Factorial Class

Comment: Subclassing won't help with making recursively-generated number sequences easier.

Comment: I have a program in which the user enters a number and it gives the value of that number in a a lot of other sequences. I'm just exploring recursion and trying to use polymorphism at the same time (I have other classes too)

Comment: You might want to tag this with the language you're using. Because when I try to run this in INTERCAL, I get errors about not using 'PLEASE' in enough statements, so I suspect it may be C# or Java or something.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, you are correct I should have. However Dukeling just edited the tags 1 minute ago and put java.

Comment: @HassaanHafeez: No problem. It was a comment intended to help you (because with the Java tag it's more likely to attract Java experts who can answer your question, instead of random people many of whom never use Java), not a judgment on your question.

Comment: You should try to explain what you want it to do. Your example code might actually compile (mainly depending on what and where n refers to in Fibonacci) so "won't work" doesn't tell us anything about your problem.

Comment: @Radiodef It says "n cannot be resolved" I want to use that n value (the number the user input) and use that value in another class which will use that number for another usage. For example the user inputs 8, I use recursion to find out the factorial of 8, and then I pass the value of 8 to the getValue method and return it. I want to use this value of 8 in my Fibonacci Sequence class so I can get the value of the index of 8. (Using more recursion)

Comment: The `n` that you are passing to get.getValues() has not been assigned anything. And when you do assign it to a value, you get.getValues() is just going to return the exact same number you sent in.

Comment: @csmckelvey I used println and it showed that the value returned to the getValues is actually 8(the number I inputted). Or maybe you're stating something completely different

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what I'm saying. You have an int, call a method with that int as a parameter, and get that same int back. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that? It seems like `getValues()` is doing nothing.

Comment: Clearly `n` is nowhere to be found in the scope of `Fibonacci#Sequence`. That doesn't tell us what you're trying to do. A couple reasons your code is not at all self-explanatory are that A) you have a method `getValue` which does nothing but `getValue` is static so it can't be overridden and B) Fibonacci extends Factorial but you create and use an instance of Factorial. You're trying to use polymorphism somehow but we have no idea what that is. We can help but you have to tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want the value of n (the user input) to be used in multiple classes. Any idea of the code which I can use to get that to happen? You can read the reply I did to Radiodef I explained it there. @Radiodef I knew that instance was a dumb move but I was trying to get the variable of n to be used in the Fibonacci class. The polymorphism stuff is irrelevant kinda, Idk why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (below) `value` is used to store user input

```
public class Factorial {
public String value;
public void sequence(){
    value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of which you want your shit.");
    System.out.println("Factorial:");
    System.out.println(fact(Integer.valueOf(value)));
    getValues(Integer.valueOf(value));
}

public static int getValues(int n){
    return n;
}
public String getValue(){return value;}
}

public class Fibonacci extends Factorial {
    //Method sequence is overridden here
    public void sequence(){
//can use getValue() here or anywhere...there is no need to use a separate object due to inheritance
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I then use that value the user inputted in my actuall Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @HassaanHafeez `value` will be visible to `Fibonacci` class due to inheritance. So you can directly access `value` inside `Fibonacci`

Comment: So basically the getValues are useless?

Comment: `getValue()`s become relevant when `value` is private

Comment: I'm trying to do this after but I keep getting an error (In my Fibonacci Class, also changed value to valueInput) for (int value = 0; value < valueInput; value++), Do I need to write something before?

Comment: It said the operator "<" is undefined for the argument int, string, so I wrote Integer inputValue = Integer.parseInt(valueInput); but it still says the same thing. Note this is in the Fibonacci Class and the String is public in the Factorial Class as suggested.

Comment: @HassaanHafeez the for loop should compare Integers `value` and `inputValue` (as per your comment) and not `valueInput` (which i guess is a String)

Comment: @boxed__l Oops, fixed that mistake but the programs starts and stops when it gets to the Fibonacci part and says the error is at int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(valueInput); Is this because it is using the valueInput of 0 since it wasn't initialized but rather given a value in my Factorial method?

Comment: @HassaanHafeez Test it out with a default value. If it is not a number then the line would throw a Number Format Expection.

Comment: @boxed__ Thanks alot! It did throw a NumberFormatException. I put the whole public String valueInput = JOption......... But now it asks me three times when I play the code

Comment: @HassaanHafeez Seems you have serious design issues. Think over the classes and the need for them.

Comment: @boxed__l Oh! I get why that happens, I think so at least. (Possibly due to my polymorphic array in my main class)

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is not really a bad abstraction here but there's not really a way to "help you fix what you're doing". There's sortof obvious reasons polymorphism just doesn't work the way you're trying to use it. As I mentioned, one of them being that static methods can't be overridden so your `getValue` can only ever return the input number. The other reason is that you're creating an instance of a superclass from within a subclass and there's *never* a reason this is necessary. You also proceed to call a static method on said superclass instance which is also unnecessary.

So the short of it is that while you came here to ask a question about a compiler error related to the variable `n`, your code shows that you are way ahead of yourself. If you want to learn polymorphism, you should [start with a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). What you said in a comment--*"want the value of n (the user input) to be used in multiple classes"*--your code in the OP isn't going to help you achieve that because it's fundamentally faulty polymorphic design. I don't mean that as an insult, it just is and you should probably start over.

Here is a more typical design that you can use as a guideline:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input);

        System.out.println(new Factorial().getResult(n));
    }
}

public interface Sequence {
    public int getResult(int n);
}

public class Factorial
implements Sequence {
    @Override
    public int getResult(int n) {
        int result = n;
        while(n > 1) {
            n--;
            result *= n;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

There is also not really an object-oriented reason here for Fibonacci to extend Factorial.

If you really wanted to include retrieving input with the Sequence class, you could do it neatly like this:

```
public abstract class Sequence {
    private static int getInput() { // static because it relies on no state
        return Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number:")
        );
    }

    public final int getResultFromInput() { // simply calls getInput and getResult
        return getResult(getInput());       // sub classes will not need to do
    }                                       // anything with this method

    public abstract int getResult(int n);   // sub classes override this method
}                                           // to provide their functionality

public class Factorial
extends Sequence {
    @Override
    public int getResult(int n) {

        // same as above factorial

    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
System.out.println(new Factorial().getResultFromInput());
```

I would argue it's not really OOP-correct for a number sequence object to do things like show dialog boxes but there's not a reason you can't *do* it.

Also, as a minor side note, you should use long instead of int. Factorials will result in overflow very quickly with int (after 12!). Not sure when exactly you get overflow from a Fibonacci sequence, certainly not as soon as factorial.

Comment: I was trying to use polymorphic arrays from my main class in a for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by polymorphic array. In my examples you can, for instance, create an array of Sequence and loop through it somehow. `Sequence[] sequences = { new Factorial(), new Fibonacci() };`

Comment: Well I saw a video yesterday that told me my very little knowledge of polymorphism. It had 4 classes just like mine with a main class and 1 super class with two subclasses that contain the same "void Sequence()" like my classes do. I created an arrayobject from my main class to my superclass Factorial and since the subclasses inherit from the super class, I made a for loop that basically processed all of their methods using arrayObject[x].Sequence();

Comment: See my updated opening paragraphs. Also if the video you watched had a `void Sequence()` with an uppercase 'S', it's probably a video you should take with a grain of salt. Java has [official code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and all methods start with a lowercase letter. Not a joke either, these conventions are well known: all Java code should follow them.

Comment: Although I agree with you, my final conferences for my class are on the upcoming Tuesday, so I can work with whatever grain of salt. Also the OP code had nothing to do with polymorphism, it was just my lack of knowledge on inheritance which I got fixed!

Comment: Generally speaking, inheritance is a kind of polymorphism. By extending a class and overriding a method the code is indeed polymorphic.